# « Nous allons les harer après le coronel » (répéter à l'infini) : fonction, applications de la dissimilation phonétique d'hier et d'aujourd'hui ?

Tags: orthographe, histoire, linguistique, phonétique, moyen-français

On dit que l'*assimilation phonétique* constitue « un type très fréquent de modification phonétique subie par un son au contact d'un son voisin ([contexte](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contexte_(linguistique))), qui tend à réduire les différences entre les deux. » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phon%C3%A9tique))) et avec certains types d'assimilation on présente comme critères de régression ou de progression la *position du son dans une syllabe* et la *force articulatoire d'un son* ; on rappelle aussi que « l'assimilation n'est pas l'extension d'un caractère acoustique d'un phonème dans le domaine d'un autre (...) mais un rapprochement articulatoire ou l'extension d'un caractère physiologique d'un phonème dans la formation du phonème voisin. » (G. Straka, ds. le *TLFi*, à [*assimilation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/assimilation)). La *dissimilation* est le phénomène opposé « par lequel deux phonèmes identiques ou présentant des caractères communs tendent à se différencier s'ils se trouvent dans le voisinage l'un de l'autre, l'un, dit dissimilateur, modifiant ou déplaçant ou supprimant l'articulation de l'autre, dit dissimilé`` » (Mar. Lex. 1951, ds. *TLFi* à [*dissimilation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dissimilation)). On en a peu [parlé](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13913) dans les questions.

L'hypothèse de M. *Ohala* sur la cause de la dissimilation c'est que les interlocuteurs « are confused by sounds that have long-distance acoustic effects » (éprouvent de la confusion quand ils sont exposés à des sons ayant des propriétés acoustiques avec *effets à longue distance* - aucune idée - mais on dit ([Wikipedia angl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissimilation).) des sons qui « frequently cause long-distance effects, such as nasaliation and pharyngealization », impliquant la [nasalisation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasalisation) et la... avec le pharynx). J'ai rencontré ici et ailleurs certains exemples...

---

Si on prend le [*colonel*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/colonel) (1543), on a déjà eu le *co(u)ronnel/-al*, *coronel* (et d'ailleurs c'est l'explication de la prononciation de ce mot en langue [anglaise](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/colonel) semble-t-il) :

> La forme *coronel* (d'abord *couronnel*, *couronnal* en 1540-46,
> *Amadis de Gaule* ds Hug.), attestée jusqu'au début du XVIIe s. (Malherbe, v. Lalanne), n'est probablement pas due à l'influence de
> l'espagnol *coronel* (FEW t. 2, p. [935a](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/59836)) mais correspond plutôt à
> un phénomène fréquent en moyen français (cf. *mérancolie* pour
> *mélancolie* *, *pil(l)ure* pour *pilule* *; Hope, p. 181 [[critique]](https://books.google.com/books?id=4WkRj0Uq3jkC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&ots=LqjIm513dl&focus=viewport&dq=Lexical%20Borrowing%20in%20the%20Romance%20Languages:%20A%20Critical%20Study%20of%20Italianisms%20in%20French%20and%20Gallicisms%20in%20Italian%20from%201100%20to%201900)).
>
> [ Trésor de la langue française informatisé, TLFi, section étymologie de *colonel* (extrait) ]

Le *DHLF/Rey* parle aussi du même *phénomène*, sans le préciser, et donne ces deux mêmes exemples (*mélancolie/pilule*).

---

Si on prend une acception ancienne du verbe [*haler*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/haler/1) (1460), on parle directement de *dissimilation* :

> Dérivé de l'ancienne interjection [*hare*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/hare2?idf=dmfXgXrmXhfj;str=0) (s.v. [*haro*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/haro) ; [[*FEW*]](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/6173)); dés.
> *-er*. La forme *haler* [comp. *harer*, 1377] provient sans doute d'une dissimilation des deux -r-, occasionnée par l'infinitif et le futur
> (cf. *FEW* t. 16, p. [151b](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/135499)), et qui a gagné les autres mots de la
> famille (cf. Tilander,  *Nouveaux essais d'étymologie cynégétique*
> , pp. 100-102 [[critique]](http://www.persee.fr/doc/scrip_0036-9772_1958_num_12_2_2994_t1_0331_0000_2)).
>
> [ Trésor de la langue française informatisé, TLFi, section étymologie de *haler* (extrait) ]

---

- Le phénomène observé avec *colonel* est-il le même que celui
  rencontré avec *haler*, soit celui de la *dissimilation phonétique* ;
  peut-on en préciser sa nature particulière (force articulatoire du R ou L, position de la syllabe ?) ; y a-t-il nasalisation ou emploi particulier du pharynx, des poumons, dans ces exemples ; doit-on simplement lire l'article sur l'assimilation *à l'envers* pour comprendre la
  dissimilation et ses types ?
- Pourquoi la dissimilation aurait-elle été plus fréquente en
  [*moyen-français*](http://www.axl.cefan.ulaval.ca/francophonie/HIST_FR_s4_Moyen-francais.htm) ([2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise#Aux_XIVe_et_XVe.C2.A0si.C3.A8cles_:_moyen_fran.C3.A7ais)) si le phénomène est articulatoire ; quelles circonstances se prêtent à la dissimilation (par opposition à l'existence de simples variantes graphiques, par opposition à l'assimilation) ; la dissimilation en français s'articule-t-elle autour du [*rhotacisme*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotacisme) comme en langue anglaise, quels sont ces *long distance effects* ; quel est le rôle historique et la fonction première de ce phénomène en langue française ; à quoi cela a-t-il servi avec *colonel* et *haler* (*coronel* serait-il moins confus que *colonel*, par exemple) ; pourquoi cela affecte-t-il la graphie et pas uniquement la prononciation ; est-ce un phénomène encore courant aujourd'hui et le cas échéant a-t-on un exemple typique ?

---

Il s'agit d'expliquer *brièvement* la fonction (historique) et la nature de la **dissimilation** phonétique en (moyen-)français, sa contribution, et d'illustrer quelques nuances au moyen des exemples ; et de savoir si l'hypothèse de M. *Ohala* trouve application en français (d'hier et d'aujourd'hui) et dans quels cas, ou si on est au courant de nouvelles hypothèses en littérature spécialisée là-dessus.

Comment: Surement hors-sujet, mais l'accent asiatique (qui ne possède pas le son [r]) est souvent moqué pour son remplacement des 'r' pas des 'l'. Il serait intéressant de savoir les raisons qui ont fait que cela a été vrai pour les indigènes.

Comment: @YohannV. Dans l'article Wiki en ang., c'est le fait de prononcer rapidement, d'où ma référence à la répétition dans le titre. Mais on a bien _ces six saucissons-ci sont si secs qu’on sait sûr que c’en sont_, et _saucisson_ n'est pas devenu _saurilon_ ou je ne sais quoi pour autant etc. En quoi l'aspect articulatoire de tout ça serait particulier en moyen-français, ce n'est pas la prononciation de prime abord. Pourquoi des mots de sa propre langue seraient-ils trop difficiles à dire, parce qu'ils sont trop proches du latin, du néerlandais etc. ?? C'est une étape de l'intégration de l'emprunt ?

Comment: Je suis désolé, je n'ai pas vos connaissances, n'y a-t-il pas de lien entre "le fait de prononcer rapidement" et "l'aspect articulatoire"? J'essaye de comprendre votre besoin et votre interrogation et j'ai noté une analogie dans le remplacement de certaines consonnes. Cela est pour vous, semble -t-il, hors de propos, pouvez vous m'expliquer pourquoi?

Comment: @YohannV. Merci, bien je n'ai aucune connaissance ou expertise particulière et je ne dis pas que ce soit hors propos. Je ne fais que relancer votre propos. Par exemple je me demande pourquoi le _saucisson_, qu'il soit prononcé rapidement ou pas, par des locuteurs pour qui c'est la langue maternelle ou pas, n'a pas fait l'objet d'une modification de sa graphie par dissimilation. En fait comme j'ai déjà dit ailleurs, ces questions touchant la phonétique sont particulièrement difficiles pour moi. Je pars de la base, et votre intuition vaut la mienne. L'article wiki en français est vide. Merci !

Comment: Je vois l'aspect articulatoire comme quelque chose de fondamental, mécanique, et je vois mal comment même la vitesse d'élocution peut l'affecter. Mais comme je dis, c'est purement spéculatif, d'où la question !

Comment: Vous avez cité : `l'assimilation phonétique [...] tend à réduire les différences entre les deux. [...] La dissimilation est le phénomène opposé [...]`. Une articulation réalisée avec une élocution rapide tendra rarement vers une articulation distincte et juste d'un mot. La rapidité requise nécessitera de *faire sauter* des voyelles, voir des syllabes. (*J'sais bien qu'c'est pas 'xceptionnel.*). J'imagine qu'une assimilation a été souvent faite pour fluidifier l'emploi régulier d'un mot et la dissimulation pour le mettre en relief au contraire.

Comment: @YohannV. Merci. Je suis plutôt d'accord avec ce que vous avancez - et donc _mettre en relief_. Pourquoi la mise en relief serait-elle nécessaire avec _harer_ ou _colonel_, mais pas avec _saucisson_ ? Maintenant une autre perspective, celle du cadre historique de l'évolution de la langue. Quelles conditions en moyen-français auraient-elles mandaté cette mise en relief ; quelles caractéristiques des mots tels que perçus à cette époque le justifiaient, ce R ds. harer ou L ds. colonel sont-ils plus exigeants phonétiquement ? Et à l'oral, mais aussi à l'écrit ds. certains cas ? Pas facile.

Comment: J'imagine qu'un *saucisson* a moins d'importance qu'un *colonel* dans un dialogue de tous les jours. Et pour *harer/haler*, son importance me semble venir de son sens. Je ne saurais développer plus avant, espérons que quelqu'un d'autre sera plus inspiré...

Comment: @YohannV. Merci, c'était un échange intéressant !

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be a pretty dissatisfactory answer, but given that there hasn't been another ventured in 3.5 months, I thought I'd share what I know.

---

For why it would be more common in moyen-français, I rather like this line from the historical summary of the period that you cited:

> Le français perdit la prérogative de se développer librement, il devint la chose des lettrés, des poètes et des grammairiens.

This process accelerated with classicism. Perhaps spoken language would be less affected, but the written record certainly swerved towards regularization after that period.

[This OQLF article](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4513) implies that dissimilation is alive and well today, however, even if the spelling does not reflect the pronunciation.

Certainly both assimilation and dissimilation are active in English, as the English Wikipedia articles make clear, despite spelling standardizations that would hide it in the written records. But the written record doesn't affect the acoustic and articulatory processes that underlie phonology.

---

I think there would likely be the same underlying cause for *harer* and *colonel*. I don't believe nasalization or phonoation would play a role in either, only the acoustic and articulatory character of [r] and [l]. Whether it's because it would be hard to pronounce two in a row or because it would be hard to distinguish two in a row is likely immaterial and difficult to establish for a particular centuries-old case anyhow, though you can sometimes guess at differentiation in modern cases. (One way in which dissimilation is not "just the reverse" of assimilation is that assimilation probably doesn't have acoustic origins, i.e. it's not done to confuse the listener!)

It [doesn't look like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_French#To_Early_Modern_French.2C_c._1700) the final "r" was silent as early as *harer* was borrowed, but one reason they might have mentioned the future tense in particular is that in *harera*, etc. the second syllable would have lost the stress and that reduction brings the two consonants still closer in the articulation (as well as moving the acoustic salience that would have possibly impeded the shift — comparing it to the similar case of English *governor* as "govenor", if you emphasize the second instead of the first syllable you can't possibly delete the "r").

Incidentally, one reason the change in *colonel* might have taken place in French and Spanish but not in Italian is that the second "l" was and is doubled in Italian. In Italian, [geminates are phonemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination#Italian) and hence presumably already sufficiently distinct from single "l".

---

More I can't say, e.g. on dissimilation in moyen-français, since I don't know. I do have contact with a historical linguistics professor focusing on Romance languages of the period, so if I have the occasion to ask her opinion I will. :)

Comment: Thank you ! Your answer is both insightful and challenging, especially as I have to reacquaint myself with this Q. which feels like it was written in a trance-like state. As you may probably not be able to imagine, it is difficult to assess such concepts with no background and ask something which is answerable and interesting for those who would answer, even more so with comparative material. Do not hesitate. What one knows may hold lots of value for the layman and nuanced tasty food for thought I prefer to half-baked certainty... and as you mentioned further edits are possible down the road.

Comment: Glad it's of some help. :) Very true, that it's hard to formulate good questions in fields one is just becoming acquainted with. If anything strikes you as needing clarification in my answer, I'll give it a shot. And if I can update this usefully I will.

Answer (score 1):

‘The long-distance acoustic effect’, selon moi, doit être compris comme la présence soutenue d'un son dans la chaîne parlée et de son incidence sur l'articulation des sons voisins, probablement due au repositionnement de l'appareil vocal, qui est plus lent que la prononciation.

Je pense par exemple au mot *inventer*, dans lequel le V, de par sa position entre deux nasales, n'est pas exactement comme celui du mot *valeur* (je sens encore un filet d'air passer par le nez lorsque je le prononce, contrairement à celui de *valeur*). En fait, même pour les mots *vent* ou *vingt*, ma prononciation du V initial est déjà altérée par ma préparation à la voyelle nasale qui suit.

---

Concernant la dissimilation, si j'ai bien compris la notion (?), j'aurais quelques exemples (qui concernent cependant tous un unique phonème).

Souvent, en français du Québec:

> - **Enfant** devient /ɑ̃fã/, et
>     **En enfantant** devient /ɑ̃nɑ̃fɑ̃tã/.
> - **Cent** se dit /sã/, mais
>     **Cent ans** si dit /sɑ̃tã/.
> - **Entendre** /ɑ̃tɑ̃dʁ(ə)/
>     **J'entends** /ʒɑ̃tã/
>     **Nous entendons** /nuzɑ̃tɑ̃dɔ̃/
>     **Malentendant** /malɑ̃tɑ̃dã/.

Il est remarquable que le phonème [ɑ̃] subisse ainsi une déformation qui n'est pas fonction du mot en absolu, mais plutôt de son voisinage.

C'est comme si l'on cherchait à distinguer le dernier son [ɑ̃] d'un mot ou d'une expression afin de donner un petit signe à l'interlocuteur que l'élocution du *concept* (je dis *concept* à défaut d'un meilleur mot) est terminée et que son cerveau peut l'analyser comme un tout terminé.

Je me demande si certaines conjugaison du verbe *faire* n'auraient pas subi ce genre de mutation par dissimilation, expliquant les prononciations [ə] de l'imparfait (*elle f**ai**sait* [ɛlf**ə**zɛ]) et des futur et conditionnel présent, où même la graphie est modifiée par rapport à l'infinitif (*nous ferons*).